# Jpa nested query for concat with like

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jpql, spring-data-jpa

the following code giving me error saying unexpected token at column 15, I'm trying to concatenate two columns and then want to match that string with like operator:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
"select p from 
   (select o,CONCAT(organizationName,'|',emailId)as txt from Organization o ) p 
   where p.txt like:%o%", Organization.class);
```

Comment: This below fine in oracle DB.
`select * from (select CONCAT(organizationName,emailId)as txt from Organization o ) p where p.txt like '%C%';`

Answer (score 0):

```
entityManager.createQuery("select o from Organization o where" +
                " o.organizationName like:sSearch or" +
                " o.emailId like:sSearch",Organization.class);
```